# CPU fan starts and stops after 1 second, after not being used for a year

Tags: motherboard, fan

I have read many topics where the CPU fan starts and stops after a second, but 95% the computers are new builds. So, I'm starting a new topic, hoping you could help me, because mine is an *old* build.

A friend helped me build a computer 3-4 years ago. I don't remember all the details, but I had an Asus F2A85M-LE motherboard, a 650 watt power supply, two Kingston 4 GB RAM DDR3 and no additional graphic card or anything. I also had two HDD hard drives, the one brand new. The computer was working perfectly on Windows 7. Then I had to live abroad for a while, so I used only my laptop for a year and the computer was closed in a carton box. It needed to be moved by one place to another, but it was done carefully by me.

I come home, I try to turn it on, the motherboard's fan starts, and after a second it stops. If I press the button again, it won't even do that. I have to turn off and on the power supply in order for the button to work again and for the fan to spin for a second.

The weird thing is that twice unexpectedly the computer powered on. Unfortunately, the first time the monitor wasn't on. I turned the PC off, connected the monitor, tried again, nothing.

The next one, I just plugged the power supply in another plug, it showed the first screen with the motherboard's brand and then nothing more. I turn the PC off, without doing NOTHING else, turn it on, and it won't boot again.

I have done the following:

- Checked if the power supply (both 4- and 24-pin) was connected right.
- Looked for any burned capacitor or something, but I didn't see anything.
- Moved the plastic jumper cap from pins 1-2 to pins 2-3 and then again to 1-2.
- Isolated the motherboard on a non-metal surface and turned on the power supply, nothing.
- Tried with none or one RAM and replaced their positions (I don't have a speaker installed, so can't tell you about the beeps).
- Removed and replaced the CMOS battery.
- Connected and tested the power supply to another PC and works OK.

What should I do now? It just seems very strange for the motherboard to have died on its own...

I will try the third step from this article too...

*[How I brought a dead motherboard back to life!](http://hipstermag.blogspot.gr/2015/11/how-i-brought-dead-motherboard-back-to.html)*

Also, I'm not very familiar with computers.. Let's say the motherboard is dead. What am I supposed to do with my HDDs even if I bought a new one? All my files are there, so I don't want to do a new Windows installation...

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation to you is to get your hands on a speaker. Even in 2016, the beeps are usually very helpful. I have one that I store in a drawer, and I pull it out whenever I think I need to hear the beeps.

If you end up having to buy new hardware, don't worry about your data. If you get a new system, you'll end-up installing the OS again anyway. So install your OS on a new drive, and connect your old drive as a secondary drive and use it for data storage and retrieval.